# Bulk upload data to production GAE DataStore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to bulk upload data to the endpoint http://my-app.appspot.com/_ah/remoteapi where my-app is the ID of my app.

This is a part of my app.yaml

```
- url: /_ah/.*
  script: google.appengine.ext.remote_api.handler.application
```

This is the command I use

```
appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --application whats-the-code --url=http://my-app.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=data/songs.xml --kind=Song --namespace=songs
```

The problem is that I am always prompted to enter the credential:

```
Please enter login credentials for my-app.appspot.com
Email: admin@some.host.com
Password for admin@some.host.com: ****
```

How can I config the app to by-pass the authentication? How can I designate the correct email/password to use in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Use `--oauth2` flag instead of user/password.

```
$ appcfg.py upload_data --oauth2 --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --application whats-the-code --url=http://my-app.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=data/songs.xml --kind=Song --namespace=songs
```

Comment: Let me check! I have built a back-office to support import/export already! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the email by --email and  appcfg can take password from standard input by setting the switch --passin. once you have -passin you can pipe in a file containing your password like below

```
appcfg.py < your all other options> --email <your email> --passin < password.txt
```

password.txt will have your password and nothing else.